# AngularJS - Manipulating the DOM after ng-repeat is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm experiencing some problems regarding manipulation of the DOM after looping through the data.

We have a jQuery slider plugin that is tied to data and works normally, but when using `ng-repeat`, we have to wrap its initialization with `$timeout` for it to work — and now that isn't even working.

I think using `$timeout` is unreliable, which makes for a bad fix. In jQuery I could use `$(document).ready()` — which was solid, but using `angular.element(document).ready()` doesn't seem to work either.

The slider directive is invoked but cannot obtain the height of the images in the slider because the images have not been loaded into the DOM — resulting in the slider having a calculated height of 0.

I'm finding it very frustrating at the moment - there must be a way to manipulate the DOM after data (in an `ng-repeat` for example) has cycled through.

The Initialization of the slider is performed as follows:

```js
var sliderLoad = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        var setHeight = elem.find('.slide:eq(0)').outerHeight(true);
        elem.css({
            height: setHeight
        });
    }, 1000);
    // Show the slider nav buttons
    elem.parent().find('.direction-nav').show();
};
```

… and here is a **[reproduction demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/S7Nv0Bb4T3ahUwD2JTC0?p=preview)**.

Comment: What is the behaviour of a slider once initialised? I think there is a better way of doing this. **EDIT**: If it's from a library a link to a demo would be great.

Comment: Hey @EdHinchliffe - I haven't quite got the slider to work in plunkr but the code looks a bit like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/PupKzfsu3uSov555Atfx?p=preview

Comment: I see the problem.. it's a tricky one. Basically the directive you have created gets compiled and linked to the scope before the transcluded content. So when you link function runs, the `ng-repeat` inside it hasn't been compiled. Thinking..

Comment: p.s. Load jquery before you load angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/S7Nv0Bb4T3ahUwD2JTC0?p=preview

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to avoid this without having that timeout. I think basically this jQuery plugin is not very angular friendly. Angular is a different way of thinking than jQuery and this plugin's implementation is very much in the jQuery mode..

Comment: Damn :( @EdHinchliffe. I was concerned about this. I'm gonna put a directive in it to detect when the ng-repeat is finished. and then broadcast a message to build the slider maybe? It's a difficult one indeed...!!! To be honest it could be ANY plugin in my opinion, Angular just seems a bit messy!

Comment: Coming from a jQuery world, perhaps it does, but actually I think the plugin's approach is messy - it relies on a specific structure in your DOM and then traverses it. If you were to build it from scratch in jQuery you could use a template in the directive, and the individual `slide` elements could handle their own styling and behaviour manipulations.

Comment: @30secondstosam, just saw your comment on detecting `ng-repeat` (after posting my answer...), you're almost there, and that's definitely an 'angulary' way of thinking about it. see my answer on where to go from there.

Comment: @30secondstosam, please tick my answer accepted if it solved your issue, thanks.

Comment: Hey @EliranMalka - we're still implementing this but I just want to say thank you again for the answer. Really appreciate the detail and time you must have taken over it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Quick-'n-Dirty it <sup><sub><sup>[(Demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xxZQq0MQVmiNw5JIeg3A?p=preview)</sup></sub></sup>

We would want to make sure that all images are loaded, so let's write a directive for that:

```js
app.directive('loadDispatcher', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                scope.$emit('$imageLoaded');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

… and attach it to the `ng-src`'d elements:

```html
<img class="thumb-recipe" ng-src="{{ object.tile_url }}" load-dispatcher/>
```

Now we can compare the number of events caught with our model, and act as needed:

```js
var loadCount = 0;
scope.$on('$imageLoaded', function () {
    if (loadCount++ === scope.videos.objects.length - 1) {
        _initSlider(); // act!
    }
});
```

## Decouple it <sup><sub><sup>[(Demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/HcBP75TPOxlW31deqKaq?p=preview)</sup></sub></sup>

This is a little disturbing, as it's not adhering to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) — any directive that will watch the `$imageLoaded` event will have to know about the model (`scope.videos.objects.length`).

We can prevent this coupling by finding out how many images were loaded without explicitly addressing the model. Let's assume that the events will be handled in an `ng-repeat`.

1. Make sure `ng-repeat` has finished, and fire an event with the items count. We can do that by attaching a controller with a sole purpose - to watch the `$last` property. Once it's found (with a truthy value), we will fire an event to notify about it:

   ```js
   .controller('LoopWatchCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.$watch('$last', function(newVal, oldVal) {
           newVal && $scope.$emit('$repeatFinished', $scope.$index);
       });
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <div ng-repeat="object in videos.objects" ng-controller="LoopWatchCtrl">
   ```
2. Now, catch the events and activate the slider initialization accordingly:

   ```js
   var loadCount = 0,
       lastIndex = 0;

   scope.$on('$repeatFinished', function(event, data) {
       lastIndex = data;
   });

   scope.$on('$imageLoaded', function() {
       if (lastIndex && loadCount++ === lastIndex) {
           _initSlider(element); // this is defined where-ever
       }
   });
   ```

There, now our directive does not have to know about the model. But, it's a bit cumbersome, now we have to tie a directive *and* a controller.

## Fold it <sup><sub><sup>[(Demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdGUfrVHetqTZHi7Dpd9?p=preview)</sup></sub></sup>

Let's extract this whole shabang into a single directive:

```js
app.directive('imageLoadWatcher', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (typeof $rootScope.loadCounter === 'undefined') {
                $rootScope.loadCounter = 0;
            }
            element.find('img').bind('load', function() {
                scope.$emit('$imageLoaded', $rootScope.loadCounter++);
            });
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$parent.$on('$imageLoaded', function(event, data) {
                if ($scope.$last && $scope.$index === $rootScope.loadCounter - 1) {
                    $scope.$emit('$allImagesLoaded');
                    delete $rootScope.loadCounter;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

… which will be applied to the `ng-repeat`ed element:

```html
<div ng-repeat="object in videos.objects" class="slide" image-load-watcher>
```

Now we can simply watch `$allImagesLoaded` e.g. in the slider:

```js
scope.$on('$allImagesLoaded', function() {
    _initSlider(element);
});
```

## Generalize it (if you want to) <sup><sub><sup>[(Demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/cIT1eKZ2P4K6TQZciA1N?p=preview)</sup></sub></sup>

We can break it down again and apply this approach app-wide to use event dispatching for *any* `ng-repeat` finish or `ng-src` load, which is not always necessary <sup>(**1**)</sup>, but can be quite useful. Let's see how:

1. Decorate the `ng-src` directive, so it sends an event when an image is loaded:

   ```js
   app.config(function($provide) {
       $provide.decorator('ngSrcDirective', function($delegate) {
           var directive = $delegate[0],
               link = directive.link;
           directive.compile = function() {
               return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                   link.apply(this, arguments);
                   element.bind('load', function() {
                       scope.$emit('$imageLoaded');
                   });
               };
           };

           return $delegate;
       });
       // ...
   });
   ```
2. Decorate `ng-repeat` to notify when it finishes:

   ```js
   app.config(function($provide) {
       // ...
       $provide.decorator('ngRepeatDirective', function($delegate) {
           var directive = $delegate[0],
               link = directive.link;
           directive.compile = function() {
               return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                   link.apply(this, arguments);
                   scope.$watch('$$childTail.$last', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                       newVal && scope.$emit('$repeatFinished');
                   });
               };
           };

           return $delegate;
       });
   });
   ```
3. Now can catch the events anywhere, e.g. in your slider directive:

   ```js
   var repeatFinished = false;
   var loadCount = 0;

   scope.$on('$repeatFinished', function() {
       repeatFinished = true;
   });

   scope.$on('$imageLoaded', function () {
       if (repeatFinished && 
                   loadCount++ === scope.videos.objects.length - 1) {
           _initSlider(); // this is defined where-ever
       }
   });
   ```

It seems to defeat the purpose, as we're back to square one, but it can be very powerful. And also — look, mommy, no new directives!

```html
<div ng-repeat="object in videos.objects" class="slide">
    <img class="thumb-recipe" ng-src="{{ object.tile_url }}"/>
</div>
```

## Put a sock in it <sup><sub><sup>[(Demo)](http://media2.giphy.com/media/pBzKCAfUyzsQM/giphy.gif)</sup></sub></sup>

[**<kbd>TL;DR, just gimme tha demo ! ! !</kbd>**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdGUfrVHetqTZHi7Dpd9?p=preview)

---

<sup>**1**. Decoration has to be considered carefully, as the result will be sending an event on each image loaded across the application.</sup>

---

<sup>**•** Overriding the `link` function will not be possible in version 1.3.x onwards.</sup>

Comment: Hey - I'll give that a try tomorrow :) thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal for javascript programming!! `newVal && scope.$emit('$repeatFinished');`!! Mind blown.

Comment: thanks, @nightgaunt, it's nice to be appreciated :) this works as almost all expressions in javascript returns a value, which can be treated as truthy or falsey (boolean). that form of writing is called functional-style coding.

Comment: Yup. It is not very often I see people using it and rarely in a case where it reduces a lengthy code.

Comment: A very nice answer but it seems that its not working with new version of Angular, e.g here in this plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/cIT1eKZ2P4K6TQZciA1N?p=preview 
Any idea anyone ?

Comment: @EliranMalka - sorry, my bad I send you the wrong plnkr, But if you add the latest angular library (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js) library instead of 1.2.14 , it will give you error

Comment: Not to rain on your parade but IMO expressions such as `newVal &&` are to be avoided as it is not a common Javascript idiom (Perl yes, Javascript no) and is less clear than simply `if (newVal)`.  Also `newVal &&` has absolutely *nothing* to do with functional programming

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - in the meanwhile, i got older and wiser, and true; such expressions have *nothing* to do with functional programming.
thanx :)